# Mongoid: belongs_to user and has_one user not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongoid, sidekiq

I have this relation

```
class User
  include Mongoid::Document
  include Mongoid::Timestamps

  has_one :linkedin_information, dependent: :destroy

class LinkedinInformation
  belongs_to :user
  field :summary, type String, default: ''

  validates :user_id, presence: true

  attr_accesible :summary
```

And in Sidekiq worker following code with valid data for @user:

```
user_lin = LinkedinInformation.create!({
  user: @user,
  summary: data["summary"]
  })
```

This worker throws an exception

Problem:
 Validation of LinkedinInformation failed.
Summary:
  The following errors were found: User can't be blank

After removing validation from LinkedinInformation class, worker saves LinkedinInformation to collection linkedin_informations but without user_id field nor @user get linkedin_information_id field.

I tried with setting explicitly class_name in User collection in case that the problem is in name of LinkedinInformation class, but nothing happened.

The part of problem can be solved with next code:

```
 user_lin: LinkedinInformation.new({
   summary: data["summary"]
   })
 user_lin.user = @user
 user_lin.save
```

Then I can only get user from user_lin, but i cannot reach user_lin from @user.

Comment: Have you tried adding `accepts_nested_attributes_for`?

Comment: @muistooshort I tried it now and **it works**! It still doesn't work with `LinkedinInformation.create!({...})`, but it works with `LinkedinInformation.new({..})` and later on setting user. Thank you! 
Why I needed accepts_nested_attributes_for?

Comment: Because that's it is for: http://mongoid.org/en/mongoid/docs/nested_attributes.html

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way to create this 1-to-1 relationship is to create an object via the object it belongs to like so...

```
@user.linkedin_information.create({})
```